# How to (re)load data in jQuery event functions?

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatables

The following code is based on the jQuery event example at https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/events_live.html

The data is displayed in the table as expected. However, clicking a row returns: "You clicked on **undefined**'s row", i.e. there is no value assigned where I would expect the file_id of the respective row.

I guess that the json data from '../api/data/uploads/' has to be realoded, however, I cannot figure out how.

Many thanks for your help.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var tab_uploads= $('#tab_uploads').DataTable( {
      "stateSave": true,
      "stateDuration": -1,
      "ajax": {
             "url": '../api/data/uploads/',
             "dataSrc": 'data'
             },
      "columns": [{ "data": 'file_id',  "title": 'File ID' },
                  { 'data': 'username',  "title": 'Uploading user' },
                  { 'data': 'supplier_id',  "title": 'Supplier ID' },
                  { 'data': 'timestamp',  "title": 'Timestamp' },
              ],
      "dom": 'Bfrtip',
      "buttons": ['pageLength', 'copy', 'csv', 'excel'],
      "order": [],
      });

  $('#tab_uploads tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    var data = tab_uploads.row( this ).data();
    alert( 'You clicked on ' + data[0] + '\'s row' );
    } );

  });
```

Comment: So it seems like maybe the ajax call isn't returning anything or isn't returning the correct thing. My hunch would be that the URL shouldn't have a relative path in it. If the URL is correct then test the api independently and see what gets returned.

Comment: Hi @michaela112358, the data is displayed in the table as expected, i.e. the ajax call works (I edited my question to be more precise about this). I believe that the data is not saved in the tab_uploads object and, hence, cannot be retrieved by the event function ... this is just a guess though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution based on this discussion: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/57563/datatable-returns-undefined-when-i-try-to-print-rowdata-in-console

> Since you are using columns.data to define your columns the data
> structure is objects not arrays. Instead of data[0] you need to use
> data.id

Which translates into using `alert( 'You clicked on ' + data.file_id + '\'s row' );` in the code above.